# Getting error deserialising JSON to List<T>

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I want to deserialize this json to a List of Product objects but i get this error:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[ShoppingList.Product]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
>   To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.

This is my code:

```
{
    "records": [
        {
            "id": "60",
            "name": "Rolex Watch",
            "description": "Luxury watch.",
            "price": "25000",
            "category_id": "1",
            "category_name": "Fashion"
        },
        {
            "id": "48",
            "name": "Bristol Shoes",
            "description": "Awesome shoes.",
            "price": "999",
            "category_id": "5",
            "category_name": "Movies"
        },
        {
            "id": "42",
            "name": "Nike Shoes for Men",
            "description": "Nike Shoes",
            "price": "12999",
            "category_id": "3",
            "category_name": "Motors"
        }
    ]   
}

public class Product
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public decimal price { get; set; }
    public int category_id { get; set; }
    public string category_name { get; set; }
}

public async Task<List<Product>> GetProductsAsync()
    {
        Products = new List<Product>();

        var uri = new Uri("https://hostname/api/product/read.php");

        try
        {
            var response = await client.GetAsync(uri);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                Products = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Product>>(content);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception )
        {
            throw;
        }

        return Products;
    }
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your Json is *not* a `List<Product>`, its an object with a single property called `records` which *is* a `List<Product>`.

So your actual C# model is this:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public List<Product> records { get; set; }
}
```

And you deserialize like this:

```
RootObject productsRoot = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(content);
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that your response JSON you've provided is an object which contains a list, but you are trying to deserialize the data into a straight list. I think all you need to do is add a second class which contains the list into your code, then deserialize using that list.

```
public class Product
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public decimal price { get; set; }
    public int category_id { get; set; }
    public string category_name { get; set; }
}

public class RootProduct
{
    public List<Product> Products {get;set;}
}
```

Then you change your deserialization portion from List to

```
RootProduct response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootProduct>(content);
```

The usage would then simply be products. response.Products to access the list of items.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your json structure. Below is an example of a json array - notice i removed the property "records".

```
[
    {
        "id": "60",
        "name": "Rolex Watch",
        "description": "Luxury watch.",
        "price": "25000",
        "category_id": "1",
        "category_name": "Fashion"
    },
    {
        "id": "48",
        "name": "Bristol Shoes",
        "description": "Awesome shoes.",
        "price": "999",
        "category_id": "5",
        "category_name": "Movies"
    },
    {
        "id": "42",
        "name": "Nike Shoes for Men",
        "description": "Nike Shoes",
        "price": "12999",
        "category_id": "3",
        "category_name": "Motors"
    }
]
```

Comment: Fair enough, you beat me to the alternative of building a more complex object. I was in the middle of that piece when your post popped up :) I didn't feel like trying to answer something that was already posted and I didn't want to delete what I had already done since it wasn't touched on by your post.

Answer (score 0):

Given this data

```
[
    {
        "id": "60",
        "name": "Rolex Watch",
        "description": "Luxury watch.",
        "price": "25000",
        "category_id": "1",
        "category_name": "Fashion"
    },
    {
        "id": "48",
        "name": "Bristol Shoes",
        "description": "Awesome shoes.",
        "price": "999",
        "category_id": "5",
        "category_name": "Movies"
    },
    {
        "id": "42",
        "name": "Nike Shoes for Men",
        "description": "Nike Shoes",
        "price": "12999",
        "category_id": "3",
        "category_name": "Motors"
    }
]
```

And this class definition

```
public class Order
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string price { get; set; }
    public string category_id { get; set; }
    public string category_name { get; set; }
}
```

The code to convert it from JSON to a C# `List<Order>` is:

```
public static List<Order> Map(string json)
{
    return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Order>>(json);
}
```